# Black cat, lonely path, grim ending?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a story I recall only vaguely, but it was haunting.
It is told from a first person perspective.
The narrator (You) are walking through a dark forest on a lonely path.
In front, leading you, is a black cat.
At the end of the story, the cat has led you to the edge of the forest.
You reach down to pet the cat, to thank it, and hundreds of black cats drop from the trees around you.  END
The ending strongly suggests (or states directly, I can't recall which) that the cats have killed (and perhaps, eaten) you.
I think I read this in a magazine, or a story collection.
I have had no luck finding it again. It is not "The Black Cat" by Poe, but in my memory, it seems very similar to the work of Ambrose Bierce, but it is certainly not "Cargo of Cat".  Suggestions? Please help!

Comment: Perhaps a choose your own adventure style thing?

Comment: No, it was a single, linear narrative.

Comment: Perhaps an introduction in a book?

Comment: I also seem to recall that it was only a few pages- a very, very short story.

Comment: Doesn't seem to fit closely, but you might look into The Cats of Ulthar by H.P. Lovecraft, which has some similar themes (e.g. cats as monsters), and the story is also referenced somewhat in The Dream-Quest of Unknown Kadath, also by Lovecraft. Both online for free.

Comment: The publication range would be between 1989-1993.  It's possible it would have been published in a psychology or fantasy/science fiction magazine at the time in an issue focusing on dreams.